# VBA Excel - overflow error on range select

Tags: excel, vba, range

I got the following code, now when I filter my results with the following and it returns no results I get an overflow error. But I don't see why. I figured it would be the fact I try to select a bad range. So I tried checking if the first cell with a value is empty or not. But that doesn't seem to help at the moment.

```
If Range("A2") <> "" Then
    iCtr = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Count + 1
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AB" & iCtr).AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="=1100" _
    , Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=1110"
End If
```

So anyone has any idea how to solve this or what the issue is?

Comment: Is the error in the first statement or the second one?

Comment: I get the error on the following line `iCtr = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Count + 1`

Comment: What is `iCtr`? is it `Integer` or `Long`? `Dim iCtr AS Long` may take care of it if number of rows is more thank ~32k

Comment: I currently have iCtr as Integer, however it would seem strange as there aren't any rows to select. But I'll give it a go and see what it gives.

Comment: I tried the code with some same data on my end, and it's working fine, so the issue could be specific to the worksheet.

Comment: Seems like making it a `Long` solved the issue, no idea why but thanks anyway!

Comment: Cool, quite often sizes of Arrays, indices etc. are better off declared in 32 bits (`Long`). I'll put the answer below, if you could please accept it? Tks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define

```
Dim iCtr AS Long
```

as that would safely let it accept range `RowCount`s of any size.

Comment: technically speaking `any` is actually limited from `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`

Comment: True, but since (at least as of Excel 2013) the maximum `Rowcount` can only be ~ 1 million, any valid return from `RowCount` can be safely accepted into `Long`. But correct point about size limits for the 32 bit `Long`, so +1.

Comment: +1 on long. Which is quicker than integer regardless.

Answer (score 2):

From information above, it is highly suspect iCtr as Integer that caused the problem. The maximum Integer is 32767, so it cannot hold large number. You can define it as Long to avoid the overflow problem.

```
Dim iCtr As Long
```

As a Long, the maximum value will goes up to 2147483647.